# RStudio Not Allowing Breaks in Code

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, rstudio

this is probably a very novice question, but one that I cannot seem to find an answer to on google. How do I insert a new line in a code without running it in RStudio. This is automatic in the RConsle, but not in the Studio version. Example:

```
  > pollutantmean<-function("P:/R/specdata/specdata","sulfate",id=1:332) +
```

I press enter and I get an error message because it ran the code. This is simple but so frustrating. Than you!

Comment: You aren't able to type it into the upper left script section?

Comment: Also if you're defining a function you need to give parameters names - not just values.

Answer (score 0):

You want to open a new script file and save your commands there.

File --> New file --> R Script

Comment: Yes. I'm new to R studio (obviously) and figured it out. Thank you.